# Can you retrieve documents in the status poll request?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there anyway to use the DocuSign API (polling) to retrieve and envelopes with status changes *and* all the documents in the same request? If not, is there a better way to do the following.

Currently, I am retrieving the envelope information using the polling for envelope status [recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/polling-for-envelope-status).

Afterward, I am using the provided EnvelopeId from the summary to get a list of the documents to loop through and download:

```
EnvelopeDocumentsResult docList = envelopesApi.ListDocuments(accountId, envelopeId);          

for (int i = 0; i < docList.EnvelopeDocuments.Count; i++)
        {
            // GetDocument() API call returns a MemoryStream
            MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, docList.EnvelopeDocuments[i].DocumentId);
            // More code below to process the documents
```

This requires that I make 3 service calls (one for status, then for the list of documents in the envelope, followed by downloading the actual document). This seems redundant and I imagine there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polling for Envelope status, you can use [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/custom-connect-configuration.htm). 
DocuSign Connect will send an HTTP POST request to the endpoint that you specify for the Connect configuration settings. You can subscribe for different triggering events in your Connect configuration, based on trigger event DocuSign will publish the message to your listerner.

When your "listener" application that resides at that endpoint receives a message from Connect, then you can do the processing of the message to know the envelope status, you may also receive envelope's documents in the XML but including document PDF Bytes in an XML message will make XML pretty big and might impact performance on your end if documents are very big.

You can find Connect details at [DS Connect](https://support.docusign.com/guides/connect-guide)

This will save lot of API calls for you, and it is better design to retrieve the data which you are interested in.

Comment: I considered using DocuSign Connect, but unfortunately that won't be an option on this specific project.

Comment: whats the issue in using DS Connect? If you can't use DS Connect, can you build a batch program? If you have list of envelopeIds, and using DS API you can get envelope status for all envelopes in one call, once you know the status then you can retrieve list of documents and document pdf. Even you can save one more call, save documentIds and envelopeIds mapping somewhere in your Database that way you will save one more call.